# Many-to-one windows file share sync

Tags: networking, migration, server-message-block, share

I am currently migrating an old file server I inherited which contains user data shares, there are numerous file shares configured with user home directories, for example:

`\\server\users1\joe.bloggs
\\server\users1\jane.bloggs
\\server\users2\bob.jones`
.. and so forth

I am in the process of migrating away from this server into a DFS namespace, and all user shares will be kept under a single path, e.g.:

`\\domain.local\users$\joe.bloggs
\\domain.local\users$\jane.bloggs`

For purposes of migration, I would like to keep the old and new file shares in sync, while I wait for folder redirection policies to apply and so forth. I initially tried this using DFS, but you can't have a many-to-one sync. I did think about configuring a DFS replication group for each folder share one by one but its not really practical, and causes issues with offline file sync because of the hidden files DFS places within the root of the folder its synchronising that the user doesn't have permissions for.

I wrote a powershell script to use robocopy on a list of folders I provide via a text file, but this isn't great as it just goes through in a loop, rather than doing any kind of intelligent sync of the folders like DFS would.

I investigate DSynchronize (dimio.altervista.org/eng/) which appears to be able to do "realtime sync" but I have to manually enter the folder paths one by one (there are a 250 user folders) so that's not really pratical either.

Does anyone have any further suggestions of ways I could achieve this

Hopefully the query makes sense and thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand. When joe.bloggs is migrated you want to keep his old data location in sync with the new data location? Why would you need/want to keep the old location in sync with the new? If that's not what you mean, then what do you mean when you say `I would like to keep the old and new file shares in sync`? Any clarification you can add would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Have you considered only syncing un-migrated users?**

When you do the migration during the user's off hours, have it sync as the last step before switching to redirection.  Once the sync and the migration are completed, move the 'old' folder to a temporary archive location (not synced) where it will be deleted after a cool down.  Once all the migrations are done for the evening, sync up the unmigrated folders.  Since the unmigrated users folders on the new, improved, share will be fairly static, the only thing you're copying is changes made on the old.  Once the user is moved, there is no real reason to copy their updated stuff back to the old share.  I say move it to archive because I'm extremely hesitant to delete data such as this before a good 30-365 day cooldown.